# Convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{3-5n|x|}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Study the convergence of the sequence
>   $$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{3-5n|x|}$$

The domain of $f_n$ is $\operatorname{dom} f_n = \mathbb R \backslash \{\pm\frac3{5n}\}$ and
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} f_n = 0$$
for every $x \in \operatorname{dom} f_n$. Therefore $f_n \to f$ point-wise on $\mathbb R$. What about the discontinuities? They tend to $0$ but $f_n(0) = f(0) = 0$, so $x=0$ has to be included.

As for the uniform convergence, we have that
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \|f_n(x) - f(x)\|_\infty = \infty \neq 0$$
so $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$. However, with $k > 0$,
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sup_{[-k, k]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{k}{3 - 5nk} = 0$$
because $f_n(x)$ is always increasing. So $f_n \twoheadrightarrow f$ on $[-k, k]$ with $k > 0$. How should I deal with the discontinuities here? Is it sufficient to exclude the intervals that contain $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to "discontinuities" is imprecise.  Each of the functions in the sequence is continuous in its domain of definition.  Similarly, the limit function which is identically zero in its domain of definition is also continuous in its domain of definition.

If you need to present this to others you may want to use more precise language.

Also, your calculation of the supremum over $[-k,k]$ is incorrect.

Comment: You're right, they are not discontinuities. So we have point-wise convergence on $\mathbb R$. Why is the supremum wrong? It's calculated on a closed interval, hence it equals the maximum. And since $f_n$ is always increasing (I've seen this from the derivative) the maximum must be attained at $f_n(k)$.

Comment: you are taking the absolute value.  The function behaves like 1/x near each of the points where it is not defined so it can't be bounded.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was excluding those points. Would saying "$f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on the intervals $[-k, k]$ which are subset of the domain" be correct?

Comment: You are excluding the points where the functions are not defined but you are not excluding points infinitely close to them where the function is defined and is infinite.

Comment: I don't understand. How should I proceed then?

Comment: That depends on where you want to get :-)